# What is the name of the group of complex matrices, determinant magnitude one?

Tags: matrices, group-theory, terminology, definition, determinant

I am wondering about the name of the group of complex matrices with
determinant of magnitude one. It has important named subgroups, of
course, but---does it have a name itself?

I don't suppose it is enormously important--you can just name it by its
definition--but it seems quite odd that a survey of several books, a
google search, a number of mathematician-colleagues and a Chat GPT4 query turned up nothing, so I thought I
would ask ... all of you.
Hard to believe---rose, lilac, orchid...but no word for flower.

Comment: I think it is SL(C), the **s**pecial **l**inear group over the complex field C

Comment: The special linear group is determinant *equal* to 1, not of magnitude 1.

Comment: I think also in the real case there is no name for the group of matrices whose determinant is $\pm 1$. I don't know the reason, but notice that in both cases this is the counter-image, through the map $det : M_{n,n}(\mathbb{K})\rightarrow \mathbb{K}$ of the set of scalars with magnitude $1$, which is homotopically equivalent to $\mathbb{K}^*$, namely the set of non-vanishing scalars.

Comment: The unitary matrices form a subgroup of $GL_n(\Bbb C)$ with $|\det(A)|=1$ for all $A$. In general, there are many nice conditions for the determinant, and we cannot have a name for all cases.

Comment: I agree with Andrea and your colleagues that I don't think this group has a name.

Comment: I just think it strange that no one has seen fit to name it (and the one with $\det=\pm 1$) in a hundred or more years of examining these things.

Comment: Surely the explanation is that this group really doesn't show up that often.  It does seem worth noodling over why it is that this fairly natural thing doesn't show up much, though.

Comment: My colleague suggests that, unlike many of its natural and important subgroups, this group is not defined by purely algebraic equations.  This suggests it may not have the nice geometric structure that one usually gets from matrix groups.